# Trouble with Chumper's DataTables plugin for laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, datatable

I'm trying to use the Chumper datatables library to display a table on a page.

I have my Invoice model

Class Invoice extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'invoices';

in my view:

```
{{ Datatable::table()
->addColumn('id','client_id')       // these are the column headings to be shown
->setUrl(route('api.invoices'))   // this is the route where data will be retrieved
->render() }}
```

Controller

```
public function getDatatable()
{
    return Datatable::collection(Invoice::all(array('id','client_id')))
        ->showColumns('id', 'client_id')
        ->searchColumns('client_id')
        ->orderColumns('id','client_id')
        ->make();
}
```

Route

```
Route::get('api/invoices', array('as'=>'api.invoices', 'uses'=>'InvoiceController@getDatatable'));
```

The table header is showing up, but there is no data beneath. Any ideas?

Getting an error too on this line of code in Chrome

```
 oTable = jQuery('#CIZatgPm').dataTable({
Uncaught Type error: undefined is not a function
```

Comment: That javascript error is saying that the dataTable function has not been defined.  Did you include the datatables javascript library in your HTML?

Answer (score 0):

This error suggests that you do not have jQuery and/or Datatables loaded before where you are running `Datatable::table()`.

The way you can resolve this is by adding jQuery and Datatables to the  of your page (or otherwise changing the Datatables javascript template to delay the loading of the datatables until jQuery & Datatables has been loaded).

Add the following to your `<head>` (make sure that you have jQuery as well!):

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.9.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
 <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.9.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```